# Dynamics AX Business Connector LogonAs failed

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, axapta, enterprise-portal, business-connector

I have an Enterprise Portal running IIS 7 on windows Server 2008 R2.

We are using Dynamics Ax 2009 Rollup 7.

Our Enterprise portal site stops working or displaying image, and I have to reset IIS to fix the problem.

Here is the error we getting and Event view;

```
*Dynamics Adapter LogonAs failed.*

Logon error : Connection with the Application Object Server could not be established.

Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.LogonFailedException
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.Logon(BC_PROXY_ACCOUNT_INFO* pBCProxyAccountInfo, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonUsingBCProxyAccount(_SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W* pImpersonatedUserAccount, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsAdapter.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)


Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector
Date:          10/22/2013 11:35:28 AM
Event ID:      1000
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      AAA-Web.Example.NET
Description:
Dynamics Adapter LogonAs failed.
Logon error : Connection with the Application Object Server could not be established.
Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.LogonFailedException   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.Logon(BC_PROXY_ACCOUNT_INFO* pBCProxyAccountInfo, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonUsingBCProxyAccount(_SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W* pImpersonatedUserAccount, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsAdapter.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)


Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="0">1000</EventID>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-10-22T15:35:28.000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>311623</EventRecordID>
    <Channel>Application</Channel>
    <Computer>AAA.-Web.EXEMPLE.NET</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>Dynamics Adapter LogonAs failed.

Logon error : Connection with the Application Object Server could not be established.

Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.LogonFailedException
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.Logon(BC_PROXY_ACCOUNT_INFO* pBCProxyAccountInfo, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonUsingBCProxyAccount(_SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_W* pImpersonatedUserAccount, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.BusinessConnectorNet.Axapta.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)
   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.BusinessConnector.Session.DynamicsAdapter.LogonAs(String user, String domain, NetworkCredential bcProxyCredentials, String company, String language, String objectServer, String configuration)

</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Is it a network issue?

Answer (score 0):

Recycle your app pool.May be it will start working.